# Wanted to count total attemps by day awk

Tags: linux, awk

im trying to count the number of ocurrences for a list in awk, actually im able to get it for each user the total attemps, but i wanted total attemps by day. I have a txt file something like:

```
ID, Event, Date, Type, Message, API, User, Protocol, Attemps

1, ERROR, 30-NOV-20, 4, TEXT, 2, user1, GUI, 9
```

i used below awk to count total attemps:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {count[$(NF-3)]++; next} {print $(NF-3), $3 "\t" count[$(NF-3)]}' file file
```

Can someone help me?

Expected output:

```
USER  ATTEMPS DATE
user1 3       20-NOV-2020
user1 6       22-NOV-2020
user2 2       01-DEC-2020
user3 4       12-NOV-2020
user3 19      18-NOV-2020
```

Comment: Isn't it exactly the same, except instead of `$(NF-3)` you use `$3`?

Comment: show some representative input and output to help us figure out what you want.

Comment: Given the comments on all submitted answer I have voted to close as the question if obviously lacking correct information.

Comment: important to provide matching input/output files so that people attempting to answer your question can verify the script's logic.

Comment: Seems that all people understand whats needed, not sure why this question is lack of information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do, but couldn't test with more data

```
$ awk -F', ' -v OFS='\t' '
          NR==1 {print $7,$NF,$3; next} 
          NF    {a[$7,$3]+=$NF} 
          END   {for(k in a) 
                   {split(k,ks,SUBSEP); 
                    print ks[1],a[k],ks[2]}}' file


User    Attemps Date
user1   9       30-NOV-20
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not using only awk but it should works if you need total attempts per day:

```
awk -F, '{print $3}' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Edit: To have total attempts per day and per user you can do following:

```
awk -F, '{print $3 $7}' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: After run it only shows all data with 1 at final, I wanted to count attemps by day for each user.

Comment: @EdwinBossman edited my answer to fit requirement: per day and per user attempts

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { map[$3]+=$NF } END { for (i in map) { print i" - "map[i] } }' file
```

Using gnu Awk, set the field delimiter to a comma and then use the 3rd field as the index for an array map and the value a running total of attempts ($NF). Once all lines are processed, we loop through the map array printing the index and the value which is the date and the attempt total.

Comment: it only shows 
- 4860

Comment: I just made an amendment to take account of the attempt field. There should be a total for each date.